# npm sub script with command line parameters

Tags: npm, command-line

I have some npm scripts that look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "exec:dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && npm run exec",
    "exec:stage": "export NODE_ENV=stage && npm run exec",
    "exec:prod": "export NODE_ENV=production && npm run exec",
    "exec": "node myapp.js"
}
```

I'd like to pass some command line arguments to `myapp.js` but this does not work:

```
npm run exec:prod -- -a 123 -b 456
```

This is apparently due to the fact that the `exec:prod` script is calling the `exec` script and apparently not passing along the command line parameters. Is there any way to achieve this while keeping the nested script calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the `npm run` command that you enter via the CLI the same as per your question. (i.e. avoid adding yet another npm special option (`--`) to it, as per @MikePatrick 's answer).

Change your npm-scripts to the following instead:

```json
"scripts": {
    "exec:dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && npm run exec --",
    "exec:stage": "export NODE_ENV=stage && npm run exec --",
    "exec:prod": "export NODE_ENV=production && npm run exec --",
    "exec": "node myapp.js"
}
```

**Note:** the npm special option (`--`) added to the end of the first three scripts.

---

### Demo

For demonstration purposes, lets say `myapp.js` is as follows:

**myapp.js**

```js
const args = (process.argv.slice(2));
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV;

console.log(nodeEnv);
console.log(args);
```

**Testing:**

- Running **`npm run exec:dev -- -a 123 -b 456`** prints:

  > `development`
  >
  > `[ '-a', '123', '-b', '456' ]`
- Running **`npm run exec:stage -- -a 123 -b 456`** prints:

  > `stage`
  >
  > `[ '-a', '123', '-b', '456' ]`
- Running **`npm run exec:prod -- -a 123 -b 456`** prints:

  > `production`
  >
  > `[ '-a', '123', '-b', '456' ]`

---

### Further info

The docs for [`npm-run-script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) describe the npm special option (`--`) as follows:

> ... The special option `--` is used by [getopt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/when-and-how-was-the-double-dash-introduced-as-an-end-of-options-delimiter) to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the `--` directly to your script ... The arguments will only be passed to the script specified after `npm run` and not to any pre or post script.

Answer (score 5):

To explicitly tell the `exec` script to pass along the arguments it gets, include another `--`.

Instead of:

```
npm run exec:prod -- -a 123 -b 456
```

try:

```
npm run exec:prod -- -- -a 123 -b 456
```

---

- The first double dash tells the `exec:dev` script, "*these args
  aren't for you, pass them along to the* `exec` *script*".
- The second double dash tells the `exec` script, "*these args aren't
  for you, pass them along to* `node myapp.js`".